# ASPNETZERO - Organization units not working?

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I read the [document on org. units](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Organization-Units) so I tried it out. I applied the changes shown in the example below to my "company" entity.

First, I created a root level org. unit and two child org. units in the app using the ASPNETZERO UI.

```
public class Product : Entity, IMustHaveTenant, IMustHaveOrganizationUnit
{
public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }

public virtual long OrganizationUnitId { get; set; }

public virtual string Name { get; set; }

public virtual float Price { get; set; }
}
```

I then created the migration and updated my database. After that I ran my application and created a new "company" in my application. When I checked the DB and looked at my "company" table the org. unit column had zeros in it?

Is there anything additional I need to do in order to make this work?

My use case is that I want each user to be assigned to a default "company" in my application. This way they dont have to keep selecting company on each form in my app. I also would like to restrict this action to an "admin" user, so that each user is assigned a company upon registration. Each user should not be allowed to change "company" on their own.

**Update**: I just found [this thread/post](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=13788&sid=7298b7bbced4c2841558af2567daf8f7#p13788). I will try this out tomorrow.

Comment: Company or Product? If you didn't assign it, then it will be 0.

Comment: @aaron I did not assign anything to the column. The example given in the docs does not mention that part. That is why I asked the question in my post, is there anything additional I need to do? I was under the assumption that it must work like when I added TenantId column into my entities.

Comment: A `User` has a one-to-many relationship with `OrganizationUnit`. It's very different from `Tenant` concept.